# iPhoto '11 is really slow to launch

Tags: macbook-pro, photos.app, performance

Ever since updating to iPhoto '11 it has become incredibly slow to launch. Using it is acceptable performance wise, but launching is terribly slow. I just closed it and reopened it to get an accurate time, and it too 3 and a half minutes! BTW, it only does the bouncy thing for a minute, then it just sits there. At first I ended up launching it multiple times because I thought it wasn't opening.

It is a 2.2 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo Mac Book Pro with 5 GB of RAM.

Everything else launches in an acceptable amount of time. Even iMovie is much faster. I have a fairly large library (75 GB), but it isn't any larger than it was before.

I've emptied the iPhoto Trash. Anything else I can do to speed it up, specifically launching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try rebuilding the library.

1. Quit iPhoto
2. Backup your iPhoto library
3. While holding <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>, relaunch iPhoto
4. Select the options to rebuild everything

[image]

Comment: Oh yeah, I remember seeing this before. I'll back things up try that.

Comment: Interesting thing is after I ran time machine to create a full backup iPhoto is now fast again. Totally bizarre.